# How to make change of any controls (of different types) on a form call a single event handler?

Tags: winforms, .net-4.0

I have a form with many text, numericUpdown and checkbox controls, plus a function that I would like to be called if any one's value changes. What's the best way to arrange this? I could make **Form1_Load** loop through all controls, applying a Case on control type to set the specific event type, but this seems clumsy. Thanks.

EDIT: Having said which, TextBox ValueChanged is not at all equivalent to numericUpDown Valuechanged, since it fires on each character. The nearest seems to be Validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you should use databinding to a domain object/view model/"DTO" class that implments `INotifyPropertyChanged` and therefore raises the [PropertyChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) when the underlying value has been changed.

Then you would need to handle the property change event notifications to decide when your "specific event type" needs to be raised. You could do this in either your UI or your domain object itself depending on what this "specific event" does.

Note that a [databinding will write to the domain object on `OnValidation` by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.binding.datasourceupdatemode.aspx) which generally fires on focus leaving the control, though depending on the behaviour of the specific control that you are bound onto you could change this to `OnPropertyChanged` which, for example, fires on every character input for a TextBox.

There's a [good intro to WinForms databinding here](http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040614.htm) if you're not already familiar with it...

Comment: Thanks Reddog. I think that's out of the scope of this simple architecture app but I'll keep in mind for the future.